# Object properties for just a specific object with python?

Tags: python, properties

So i have an object properties panel but the values set are identical across every object. So for example I have an int value on a cube set to 2 but then all objects are now set to 2. How could  that value be set to just that cube as selecting another object will use the same value? Code:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Test",
    "author": "",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 75, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "New Addon",
    }

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector
from bl_operators.presets import AddPresetBase


from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )




def initprop():
    bpy.types.Scene.IntCheckpoint = bpy.props.IntProperty(
    name="Check Point",
    description="Checkpoints to prevent skipping certain paths",
    min=-1, max=99999,
    default=-1) #-1 disables a check!



def delprop():
    del bpy.types.Scene.IntCheckpoint


class ObjectPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello from Object context"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        obj = context.object
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label("First row")
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.alignment = 'EXPAND'
        row = layout.row()
        row = layout.row()
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        scn = bpy.context.scene
        col.prop(scene, "IntCheckpoint") #This needs to be changeable for each object
        row = layout.row()







# Registration

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    initprop()


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    delprop()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The code should work in blender's text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property is being created for the scenes, when you want to create it for the objects. So this:

```
bpy.types.Scene.IntCheckpoint
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
bpy.types.Object.IntCheckpoint
```

And then in your panel you'll change this:

```
col.prop(scene, "IntCheckpoint")
```

to this:

```
col.prop(obj, "IntCheckpoint")
```

So to create a property specific to a type, you have to use that type in your property declaration.